# Seleccionar automaticamente un SELECT

Tags: php, html, html5, html-select

buenas tardes les agradeceria que me ayuden, les explico mi problema:
estoy haciendo una opcion de editar solicitudes las cuales se muestran en una tabla, entonces al momento que se haga clic sobre el boton de editar este me redirecciona a un html que recibe los datos de esa solicitud y los llena en el formulario para poder editar, mi problema es al momento de llenar un select este se debe seleccionar la opcion que tiene guardada la solicitud, les agradeceria su ayuda lo que actualmente hago es crear otra opcion con el dato recibido pero se crea repetido este dato en el select:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="Venta">Credito Aprobado:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><select class="form-control " name="credito_aprobado" required data-bv-notempty-message="Por favor seleccionar" disabled="disabled"><option value="<?php echo $data->tcc?>"><?php echo $data->tcc?></option><option value="SI">SI</option><option value="NO">NO</option></select></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hola william podrias por algo de codigo. 
Que tienes hecho hasta el momento 
Te muestra algun error  Etc Etc

Comment: Que valor retorna este codigo `echo $data->tcc` ?? un String "Si" o "No" ?

Comment: buenas adjunté el codigo que me llena el select, no me sale ningún error lo que me hace es duplicar la opcion que esta ingresada ya que la trae y crea otra opcion porque aun no consigo hacer que se seleccione la que está guardada en la BD

Comment: retorna un String "Si" o "No" dependiendo de cual tenga almacenado la solicitud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el valor de `$data->tcc` es un "SI" o un "NO" para evaluar cual opcion debe estar seleccionada deberias hacer lo siguiente

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="Venta">Credito Aprobado:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="form-control " name="credito_aprobado" required data-bv-notempty-message="Por favor seleccionar" disabled="disabled">
            <option value="SI" <?php if($data->tcc == 'SI') { echo "selected=\"selected\""; } ?>>SI</option>
            <option value="NO" <?php if($data->tcc == 'NO') { echo "selected=\"selected\""; } ?>>NO</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias ya lo había hecho pero de una forma mas larga con lo tuyo minimizo código GRACIAS!!!!!